# Can I automatically sort a grouped and stacked pivot chart by a sum of values without showing this on the chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am working with data in groups in Excel.  I currently have a pivot table and chart set up with:

- Rows: `symptom name` grouped into one of four `international severity grades`
- Columns: four datasets - `mild`, `severe`, `both` or `not specified`.

I need to present these as a stacked bar chart, which I have been able to do as below:[image: image of stacked bar chart as it currently looks]

As you can see, they are grouped into their `international severity grades` nicely but are arranged randomly within their groups.  I would like them to be sorted descending by the sum of `mild + severe + both + not specified` within their groups, but I can't find a way to do this.

The closest I have come so far is to have a calculated field that works out this field - but then this displays as a fifth column category on the graph and I can't seem to remove it.

Does anyone have a way to do this?  I think I may be able to drag and drop them into the right positions, but this will take a while so if there is a better way I would be really grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Grand Total for rows to the pivot table, then sort the grand total column. This will not add a series to the chart, but the items display sorted by total.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like exactly what I wanted, however in my spreadsheet I couldn't get Grand Total to show for Rows. My Pivot Table was arranged as: http://imgur.com/a/cB76K

Comment: Urghhh, Mac. Everything is different on the Mac and ten years behind modern Excel. In Excel for Windows there is a ribbon command. Pivot Table Design tab > Grand Totals > On for Rows Only. Or it can be set in the Pivot table options dialog on the Totals and Filters tab. I added two screenshots above. Now, I don't know if that exists on the Mac. It only recently received slicers, which were added to Windows Excel with version 2007.

Comment: Thanks teylyn - the option is there and just doesn't do anything.  Interestingly I had the same behaviour in excel for windows (which the document was created in).  I'll retest in a few days and see if I get anywhere.  If not will happily accept your answer as it seems to have worked for your test data